# Struggling with C#, reading from XML in my generator

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, random

I gave up on doing this in Excel, so I made a XML file  (named "ideas.xml") looking like this:

```
<ideas>
<verbs>
    <verb>Verb1</verb>
    <verb>Verb2</verb>
    <verb>Verb3</verb>
    <verb>Verb4</verb>
    <verb>Verb5</verb>

</verbs>
<adjectives>
    <adjective>Adjective1</adjective>
    <adjective>Adjective2</adjective>
    <adjective>Adjective3</adjective>
    <adjective>Adjective4</adjective>
    <adjective>Adjective5</adjective>
</adjectives>
<nouns>
    <noun>Noun1</noun>
    <noun>Noun2</noun>
    <noun>Noun3</noun>
    <noun>Noun4</noun>
    <noun>Noun5</noun>
</nouns>
</ideas>
```

I'm trying to make a generator that prints out a random verb, adjective and noun like this. Here is the piece that I'm struggling with:

```
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load("ideas.xml");

        Random r = new Random();
        XmlNodeList verbTag = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("verb");
        XmlNodeList adjectiveTag = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("adjective");
        XmlNodeList nounTag = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("noun");


        textBox1.Text = ((verbTag[0].InnerText) + " " + (adjectiveTag[0].InnerText) + " " + (nounTag[0].InnerText)) + ".";
    }
```

I'm trying to add a randomizer to the output but I can't seem to get it right. Also, I print out the first value in the arrays just to get it to work, any tips on how to pick a random number between 0 and the last one would be really sweet.

Any help, hint or suggestion is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your `r` variable (which is `Random` class instance) to generate indexes, instead of hardcoded `0`s like in your code:

```
textBox1.Text = ((verbTag[r.Next(0, verbTag.Count - 1)].InnerText) + " " + (adjectiveTag[r.Next(0, adjectiveTag.Count - 1)].InnerText) + " " + (nounTag[r.Next(0, nounTag.Count - 1)].InnerText)) + ".";
```